# using mysqldump on process.start nothing happens, but when I try the argument on cmd it is working

Tags: mysql, process.start

I'm spending hours on troubleshooting this. I have this code

```
    Dim drive_name As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\database"

    Dim db_name As String = "sample_db.sql"

    Dim argument As String = "-u root sample_db table1 > """ & drive_name & "\" & db_name & """"
    Try
        Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe", argument)
        Console.WriteLine("Argument:  " & argument)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error:   " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

By looking at the `console.writeline`, it output like this

```
-u root sample_db table1 > "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MyProjectPath\bin\Debug\database\sample_db.sql"
```

But by checking `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MyProjectPath\bin\Debug\database\` I can't see `sample_db.sql`, so I open mysqdump copy the `console.writeline` and paste it to cmd. I now have this on mysqldump

```
C:\Users\MyName>C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u root sample_db table1 > "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MyProjectPath\bin\Debug\database\sample_db.sql"
```

By executing that on mysqldump it works.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Im surprised at the use of lessthan, I would have expected greaterthan

Comment: Oh, sorry! It's just a typo.

Comment: :) ok thats fair enough in which case have you tried using the process.StandardOutput option to open a stream and write it and so on?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't tried that.  I'am familiar on using `process.StandardOutput`. Will it be better?

Comment: Cary's solution below should work too - but there is a standardinput and a standardoutput, and you can use them much like something | mycommand and mycommand > stuff dont have mysql cant install it here (big brother is watching) to test, but it is a very good way of collecting the output and doing something with it..

Comment: Oh, I'd love to see that. Will you please post an answer with that approach?

Comment: OK, but my example wont be an sql dump - but, I'll show a how to use

Comment: Sure sir! Thank you so much. I'd love to see use a better approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the suggestion of [`BugFinder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36618372/2947415) I am now able to use `standardInput` and standardOutput`

**Code for import:**

```
    Try
        Dim myProcess As New Diagnostics.Process()
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\"
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.Start()
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
        Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        createDatabase()
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u  root  sample_db < " & drive_name & "\" & db_name)
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        myProcess.WaitForExit()
        myProcess.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error on Import: " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

If you want to change it to import, simply change this line of code to your desired mysqldump export command:

```
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u  root  sample_db < " & drive_name & "\" & db_name)
```

Example of export command

```
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u  root  sample_db > " & drive_name & "\" & db_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this doesnt use mysql (as I dont have it) the principal applies.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/all";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
String output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\log.txt",output);
p.WaitForExit();
```

in log.txt was my output as expected.

so in your case, you have the mysqldump command in filename, arguments in arguments, and change the writealltext to your output file

Obviously you can then use this to be far more creative should you desire, size for example maybe an issue, after all if you have gb of data, storing it all in one string is possibly asking a bit much, but the output is a stream, so realistically you could work further and work with the stream more directly and output chunk by chunk

Comment: Thanks! Because of your example I am now able to look for that kind of backup and restore. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/726407/MYSQL-Database-Backup-Restore

Answer (score 0):

[In this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/62acea83-236b-4f55-8eec-25d80df5df66/backup-restore-mysql?forum=Vsexpressvb&prof=required) a user suggested to change the `>` to `-r`

So instead of

```
Dim argument As String = "-u root sample_db table1 > """ & drive_name & "\" & db_name & """"
```

You will now have

```
 Dim argument As String = "-u root sample_db table1 -r """ & drive_name & "\" & db_name & """"
```

And it will **work**!